# Is it efficient to import the complete aws-sdk

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-nodejs

I'm using the `AWS SES` service for sending Email notifications. Below is the respective `js` file responsible for sending the customized Email using the templates.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const { models } = require('../api/sequelize');

let destination = '';
let questionId = '';
let userId = '';
let answerId = '';
let answerBy = '';
let questionBy = '';

class AnswerNotifcation {
  constructor(qId, uId, aId) {
    questionId = qId;
    userId = uId;
    answerId = aId;
  }

  async notification() {
    try {
      const answerByDetail = await models.answer.findByPk(answerId, {
        include: [{
          model: models.user,
          attributes: ['fullName', 'userName', 'userId', 'email'],
        }]
      });

      const questionByDetail = await models.question.findByPk(questionId, {
        include: [{
          model: models.user,
          attributes: ['fullName', 'userName', 'userId', 'email'],
        }]
      });

      const notification = models.notification.create({
        userId: questionByDetail.userId,
        senderUserId: answerByDetail.userId,
        message: 'Answered your question',
        redirectLink: `/q/${questionByDetail.slug}#${answerByDetail.answerId}`,
        isRead: 'false',
        type: 'answers',
        isHidden: 'false'
      })

      destination = questionByDetail.user.email;
      answerBy = answerByDetail.user.fullName;
      questionBy = questionByDetail.user.fullName;

      this.sendNotification(destination, answerBy, questionBy)

    } catch (err) {
      console.log('\n\tError sending email notification \n\t', err);
    }
  }

  sendNotification(dest, aBy, qBy) {
    AWS.config.update({
      region: "us-east-1"
    });
    this.ses = new AWS.SES({ apiVersion: "2010-12-01" });
    this.params = {
      "Source": "no-reply@testing.com",
      "Template": "Answer_Template",
      "ConfigurationSetName": "testConfig",
      "Destination": {
        "ToAddresses": [dest]
      },
      "TemplateData": `{\"receiverName\":\"${qBy}\",\"senderName\":\"${aBy}\", \"description\":\"Answered Your Question\"}`
    }
    console.log("Sending notification for answer");
    this.ses.sendTemplatedEmail(this.params, (err, data) => {
      if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
      else console.log(data);
    });
  }
}
module.exports = AnswerNotifcation;
```

My question is that is it a good approach to import the complete `aws-sdk` rather than importing the packages which we only need(in the above code it's `AWS.config` and `AWS.SES` which I'm using).

Which is the efficient approach importing the complete `aws-sdk` or else importing only the services we're using like `import { <ServiceName> } from 'aws-sdk'`?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/modular-packages-in-aws-sdk-for-javascript/

Answer (score 1):

It's better practice loading only AWS SDK that you will be working with. For example, if you want to work with S3, then use:

```
const {S3} = require('@aws-sdk/client-s3');
```

More information, see the [AWS JavaScript DEV Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/loading-the-jssdk.html).